# how to take json key value based on id

Tags: angular, typescript

i need to retrieve Type based on my file number and File Volume Number

```
[
  {
    ApplicantPartySiteNumber: "60229",
    ManufacturerPartySiteNumber: "1095651",
    FileVolumeNumber: "E312534.2",
    Type: "Manufacturer",
    FileNumber: "E312534"
  },
  {
    ApplicantPartySiteNumber: "1095651",
    ManufacturerPartySiteNumber: null,
    FileVolumeNumber: "E63418.1",
    Type: "Applicant",
    FileNumber: "E63418"
  },
  {
    ApplicantPartySiteNumber: "1095651",
    ManufacturerPartySiteNumber: null,
    FileVolumeNumber: "E61772.2",
    Type: "Applicant",
    FileNumber: "E61772"
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const data = [{  
      "ApplicantPartySiteNumber":"60229",
      "ManufacturerPartySiteNumber":"1095651",
      "FileVolumeNumber":"E312534.2",
      "Type":"Manufacturer",
      "FileNumber":"E312534"
   },
   {  
      "ApplicantPartySiteNumber":"1095651",
      "ManufacturerPartySiteNumber":null,
      "FileVolumeNumber":"E63418.1",
      "Type":"Applicant",
      "FileNumber":"E63418"
   },
   {  
      "ApplicantPartySiteNumber":"1095651",
      "ManufacturerPartySiteNumber":null,
      "FileVolumeNumber":"E61772.2",
      "Type":"Applicant",
      "FileNumber":"E61772"
   }]
   
   const result =  data.map(res=>({'FileNumber': res['FileNumber'], 'FileVolumeNumber': res['FileVolumeNumber']}));
   
   console.log(result)
```

Comment: no am getting result like this ({FileNumber: undefined})

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are missing in your json and the instructions are not clear, sorry

Comment: i have my file number(E312534) and FileVolumeNumber(E61772.2) if i pass this value i need to take Type of that object . For this value type is 'Manufacturer' you can see in that string

Answer (score 0):

Use the array find method e.g.

```js
  var obj=this.fileArr.find(x=>x.FileVolumeNumber == "E312534.2" && x.FileNumber == "E312534");
  if(obj)
  {
    alert(obj.Type);
  }
```

Please refer to this [Stack-Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4fvd7).

Thanks.